# Chrome on Android does not expand header element on orientation change

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, orientation

I've only tested this in Chrome and the stock browser on Android 4.0.4 for a Droid Razr. When I use the following markup, any `<hx>` elements will not expand the full width of the screen when rotating from portrait to landscape view. Refreshing the browser in landscape does cause those elements to expand the full width. The body width is expanding but the hx elements retain their portrait width.

This works as it should in the stock browser and is not a problem for other block elements such as p or div. Am I forgetting something?

```
<!doctype html>  
 <meta name=viewport content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
 <h1>Around the rugged rock the ragged rascal ran. Around the rugged rock the ragged</h1>
```

Comment: Filed this bug report. Note the related bug in the comments: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caused by a bug in chrome. the best work around i have found comes from https://code.google.com/u/114845687405761252904/ and is to force a redraw on orientation change

```
        

if (/\bAndroid\b.*\bChrome\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

        document.querySelector("body").style.display = "none";

        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("body").style.display = "block";
        }, 1);

    }, false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this very issue today. Unless we're both forgetting something, this is definitely just a bug in Chrome. I noticed the issue on my Nexus 7 running 4.1.2.